# Can't select text in input card

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have some trouble with this card of bootstrap. 
I've create a navigation card with input text with a floating label.
My problem is that I can't select text inside the input.

```
<form class="form-floating">
    <p><br></p>
    <div class="container-lg">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="card text-center col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home3">F1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu31">F2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="home3" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
                        <h5>Flash 1 Delay</h5><br>
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <input type="text" id="flashdelay1" class="form-control" placeholder="Flash1" required="" autofocus="">
                            <label for="flashdelay1">Flash 1 Delay (ms)</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu31" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
                        <h5>Flash 2 Delay</h5><br>
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <input type="text" id="flashdelay2" class="form-control" placeholder="Flash2" required="" autofocus="">
                            <label for="flashdelay2">Flash 2 Delay (ms)</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu32" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
                        <h5>Flash 3 Delay</h5><br>
                        <div class="form-label-group">
                            <input type="text" id="flashdelay3" class="form-control" placeholder="Flash3" required="" autofocus="">
                            <label for="flashdelay3">Flash 3 Delay (ms)</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

Have any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Select input text with parameter `value`

using Jquery

```
#InputID.val
```

using javascript

```
document.getelementbyid(InputID).value
```